# Tomcat 10.1 try to load custom tags but class not found "javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag"

Tags: jsp, custom-tags, jakarta-migration

I run into a problem with an upgrade to Spring Boot 3. For the layout we use JSP and defined the base layout in a custom tag `<t:baseLayout>`. After upgrading to Spring Boot 3 and Tomcat 10.1 the system can't load the custom tags anymore.

```
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<t:baseLayout>
    Test
</t:baseLayout>
```

This was working before. When I run it now I get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1437) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.7]
    ... 182 common frames omitted
```

I know that the **"javax"** namepace isn't supported anymore in that part but it have haven't defined it. Does anyone know how to solve that problem?

Just in case, I'm also using JSTL

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core" %>
```

and this part is working fine and I have installed the following packages.

```
implementation group: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api', version: '3.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.web', name: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl', version: '3.0.1'
```

Comment: I guess you have homemade tag(tld) in your directory (`/WEB-INF/tags`), it is not rewritten to use `import jakarta.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag`, but still uses ` import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag`. So check your custom tag(tld) java code, rewrite and recompile.

Comment: @life888888 it's a custom tag but in the whole template there is not import. This happens under the hood that is the problem. I have searched in the tree for javax there are some classes that are ok but the javax.servlet.jsp is not listed in the project.

Comment: I stumbled upon this whilst trying to sort out a similar issue, the error I get looks more like {java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: public abstract jakarta.servlet.DispatcherType jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest.getDispatcherType() is not supported} I'm trying to move a project from Spring Boot  3/springframework 6 up, I was having issues with a jsp taglib (which relied on the security taglib). I found this page which I hope will help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/migration/servlet/authentication.html

Comment: @BillNaylor in the end i have migrated my templates to Thymeleaf. I have found no solution in this case.

Comment: I shall update after I've tried out what's suggested, after 10:00 P.M. right now!

Answer (score 0):

So in the end i found no working solution for this problem so i migrated the templates to Thymeleaf. There are several libs that didn't work with the tags.